# Web Forms For Marketters (WFFM) Html input tag with placeholder attribute

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a requirement in which I'm implementing sitecore WFFM to create a form. The page has HTML input tags with Placeholder attribute. I have to render the WFFM SingleLineInput box to a input tag with placeholder attribute. What should I do?

I know that the `SingleLineText` class is define in the `Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls` dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by extending `SingleLineText` with an additional property to store the placeholder's text value. Once the property is in place, you'll need to override the `OnInit` method and inject the placeholder attribute if one happens to be set.

```
public interface IPlaceholderField
{
    string PlaceholderText { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the custom implementation of `SingleLineText`

```
[ValidationProperty("Text")]
public class SingleLineText : Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.SingleLineText, IPlaceholderField
{
    [VisualCategory("Custom Properties")]
    [VisualProperty("Placeholder Text", 2)]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string PlaceholderText { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set placeholder text, if present
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PlaceholderText))
        {
            textbox.Attributes["placeholder"] = PlaceholderText;
        }

        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}
```

Finally, you will need to create a new field item definition under `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field Types/Custom/` and set the assembly to use the class above. Your new placeholder property should appear under a "Custom Properties" category when you have the field selected in the Form Designer.

Comment: Hi guys, Does this still apply for WFFM 8.1 ?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using MVC version of WFFM you need to add following as explained in approved answer

1- Create a class

```
 public interface IPlaceholderField
{
    string PlaceHolder { get; set; }
}

[ValidationProperty("Text")]
public class SingleLineText : Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.SingleLineText, IPlaceholderField
{
    [VisualCategory("Custom Properties")]
    [VisualProperty("Placeholder", 2)]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string PlaceHolder { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set placeholder text, if present
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PlaceHolder))
        {
            textbox.Attributes["placeholder"] = PlaceHolder;
        }

        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}



public class ExtendedSingleLineTextField : Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.Fields.SingleLineTextField, IPlaceholderField
{
    [VisualCategory("Custom Properties")]
    [VisualProperty("Placeholder", 2)]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string PlaceHolder { get; set; }

}
```

2- Copy Single-Line Text from **/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field** Types/Simple Types/Single-Line Text to **/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field Types/Custom**
 set Assembly,Class and MVC Type

[image]

3-Create a new chtml file under \Views\Form\EditorTemplates  ane name it ExtendedSingleLineTextField.cshtml it should be same name with the class name(**ExtendedSingleLineTextField**)

```
@using Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Html
@using LendLease.Web.HtmlHelpers
@model  LendLease.Extension.Sc.WFFM.ExtendedSingleLineTextField


@using (Html.BeginField())
{
    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Value, new { placeholder = Model.PlaceHolder })*@
    @Html.ExtendedBootstrapEditor("value",Model.PlaceHolder,"",new []{""})

}
```

add a html helper so you can inject placeholder i named it BootstrapEditorHtmlHelperExtension.cs

```
  public static class BootstrapEditorHtmlHelperExtension
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ExtendedBootstrapEditor(this HtmlHelper helper, string expression, string placeholderText, string inlineStyle, string[] classes)
    {
        var str = string.Empty;
        var viewModel = helper.ViewData.Model as IViewModel;
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            var styleSettings = viewModel as IStyleSettings;
            if (styleSettings != null)
            {
                str = styleSettings.CssClass;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(placeholderText))
            {
                 placeholderText = viewModel.Title;
            }
        }
        return helper.Editor(expression, new
        {
            htmlAttributes = new
            {
                @class = (string.Join(" ", classes) + " form-control" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? string.Empty : " " + str) + (helper.ViewData.Model is SingleLineTextField ? " dangerousSymbolsCheck" : string.Empty)),
                placeholder = placeholderText,
                style = (inlineStyle ?? string.Empty)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it really helps me alot :)

Comment: what would be in case of multi-cultured website ? as a workaround we would go for dictionary item

Comment: I used this method to create my placeholder text and it works great, but for some reason the text does not translate when I create another language version. The text I add to the field for the other language also overrides all other versions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to create a Custom Field. And It works fine :)

```
internal class CustomType : SingleLineText
{
    [VisualProperty("Placeholder", 100)]
    [VisualCategory("Appearance")]
    public string placeholderText
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    protected override void DoRender(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        this.textbox.Attributes.Add("placeholder", this.PlaceholderText );

        base.DoRender(writer);
    }

}
```

Then i just created an Field Type Item under **/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Field Types/Custom** and entered assembly and class details in the item.

Works like a charm...!!