# Shared field for sitecore Web form for marketers custom field attributes

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

I am using sitecore 8.1 with MVC and i was required to have a single-line text  & Email fields in web forms for marketers with placeholder text.
I have successfully created a custom text field with placeholder but have a minor issue that it's not a shared field or multi-cultured supported.
I have followed @azadeh-khojandi reply for mvc [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718911/web-forms-for-marketters-wffm-html-input-tag-with-placeholder-attribute)

I have a last solution to take a dictionary key in placeholder and from code get key's value which is not supposed to be a good idea.
Any hint or guide ?

**Classes**:

```
[ValidationProperty("Text")]
public class SingleLineText : Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.SingleLineText, IPlaceholderField
{
    [VisualCategory("Custom Properties")]
    [VisualProperty("Placeholder", 2)]
    [DefaultValue("")]        
    public string PlaceHolder { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set placeholder text, if present
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PlaceHolder))
        {
            textbox.Attributes["placeholder"] = Helper.GetDictionaryItem(PlaceHolder);
        }

        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}

public class ExtendedSingleLineTextField : Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.ViewModels.Fields.SingleLineTextField, IPlaceholderField
{
    [VisualCategory("Custom Properties")]
    [VisualProperty("Placeholder", 2)]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string PlaceHolder { get; set; }
}
public interface IPlaceholderField
{
    string PlaceHolder { get; set; }
}

public static class BootstrapEditorHtmlHelperExtension
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ExtendedBootstrapEditor(this HtmlHelper helper, string expression, string placeholderText, string inlineStyle, string[] classes)
    {
        var str = string.Empty;
        var viewModel = helper.ViewData.Model as IViewModel;
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            var styleSettings = viewModel as IStyleSettings;
            if (styleSettings != null)
            {
                str = styleSettings.CssClass;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(placeholderText))
            {
                placeholderText = viewModel.Title;
            }
        }
        return helper.Editor(expression, new
        {
            htmlAttributes = new
            {
                @class = (string.Join(" ", classes) + " form-control" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? string.Empty : " " + str) + (helper.ViewData.Model is SingleLineTextField ? " dangerousSymbolsCheck" : string.Empty)),
                placeholder = placeholderText,
                style = (inlineStyle ?? string.Empty)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**View for Custom Field**:

```
@using (Html.BeginField())
{    
    @Html.ExtendedBootstrapEditor("value", Model.PlaceHolder, "", new[] { "" })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolve this issue by adding `[Localize]` attribute for PLaceholder in "**ExtendedSingleLineTextField**" and "**SingleLineText**" class.

This was defined here `Sitecore.Form.Core.Attributes.LocalizeAttribute` and also for further customization reference.

**Page 27**:
https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web_forms_for_marketers_v2_reference_usletter.pdf