# How to add add a custom attribute for each input field in Sitecore Webforms for Marketer

Tags: sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, custom-attribute

I am using Sitecore 8.1 with WFFM for marketer.
I have to add one additional input attribute called "custom_attr" in each field of webform ( textbox,radiobtn,checkbox,dropdown) and editor can add some text inside it and it will render in UI .

How to add a custom input attribute that display when html get render in Sitecore Webform for marketer in MVC i.e.

```
<input type='text' custom_attr='some_msg'/>
<select custom_attr='some_msg'><option></option><select>
<input type='chekbox' custom_attr='some_msg'/>
<input type='radio' custom_attr='some_msg'/>
```

Is there we have a global way to add this attribute in one place and it render for all fields ?

Comment: You can achieve this by extending the files as given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718911/web-forms-for-marketters-wffm-html-input-tag-with-placeholder-attribute post

Comment: Also you can achieve this by Jquery take the specific classes on elements in WFFM and apply attribute with the help of these css classes